# Entity Framework Database First - Map to Generic List

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using **Entity Framework - Database First** in my project. My model has a view with only one `VARCHAR` column:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
SELECT 'Eris' Eris
FROM MyTable
```

By default, this view gets mapped to its own entity with just one property:

```
public virtual DbSet<MyView> MyViews { get; set; }
```

How can I change this so that the view gets mapped to a List of strings instead:

```
public virtual List<string> Eris { get; set; }
```

Comment: Please show some code so we can see what you've tried and exactly how it's not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately EF does *not* support mapping collections of value types. If you really want to implement this scenario then you might want to look into other ORM frameworks that have this feature like [*NHibernate*](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html).

If that's not an option and you have to stick to EF then you're forced to create an entity with one property like you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score -1):

The entity model represents one element in the table.
When you retrieve data from the table, you will get a list of entity model objects.

Comment: What are you saying and what does it have to do with my question?

Comment: I say that it has no sense to have a list of strings in your entity as an entity represents one element in your view. If you want to represent the list of elements in your view you'll do it having a list of entity model objects.

Comment: @IsaacKleinman, after the edition of your question, you may have a `MyView` class with a property `public string Eris { get; set; }`. The `DbSet<MyView>` property represents the Entity in the DbContext. You are misunderstanding this with the Entity model definition.